# momentjs change string mm/yyyy format to yyyy-mm

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have a `date` string `11/2004` that comes to me via an API and on mobile I am trying to display this on a `date` field.

If i try to render this as it is I see the following warning on console

> The specified value "11/2004" does not conform to the required format.
>   The format is "yyyy-MM" where yyyy is year in four or more digits, and
>   MM is 01-12.

so using momentjs i thought this should be easy to change to date or month format but i am struggling with it as i cant seem to get the output i want.

I tried the following code but that give me `invalid date`

```
moment('11/2004').format('yyyy-MM')
```

What am i doing wrong here? How do i display the date on an input field in the correct format? I cant change the field type to anything else as its a date picker field on mobile.

Comment: Try creating your moment date like this `moment('11/2004','MM/YYYY')` also change your format to `YYYY-MM`

Comment: And it's `YYYY` and not `yyyy` -> https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: You should always provide the format when parsing strings, otherwise you're leaving it up to chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation on parsing](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) what you need to do is created your moment object with the format specified.

```
moment('11/2004','MM/YYYY')
```

This will set the day to the first, but the month and the year to the ones specified.

Also, your format is wrong, the `yyyy` should be capital `YYYY`

So your final code should look like this

```
moment('11/2004', 'MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create your date with the [string-format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

```
moment('11/2004', 'MM/YYYY')
```

and then display it using the `format()` function

```
moment('11/2004', 'MM/YYYY').format('YYYY-MM')
```